# Как конвертировать МФА в речь с помощью Python

Tags: python, модули, text-to-speech

Какой модуль использовать чтобы конвертировать [МФА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82) в речь на mac os x в python ? Желательно, чтобы были функции по настройке голоса как в pyttsx3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону модуля **ipapy**.
Также почитайте на английской версии стака: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911028/python-arpabet-phonetic-transcription

Вот Вам еще одно видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9UXmb4TYZs

Comment: у меня не работает espeak как поправить:
`2019-07-02 12:02:38.168 espeak[3358:295585] 12:02:38.166 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.`
ipapy хорошая библиотека ,но она позволяет 
работать с МФА ,но не воспроизводить.

Comment: Лучше напишите отдельный вопрос про `espeak`. Используйте ipapy для работы с МФА и конвертации в "человеческий язык", а далее ищите библиотеку, которая умеет воспроизводить речь.

Comment: Я хочу воспроизводить речь на [конланге](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Искусственный_язык).Поэтому и спрашивую про МФА.